# How to merge two AndroidManifest file in Unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, flurry, vuforia, prime31

I am using Vuforia in my Unity3d project and i am also using Prime31 plugin for Flurry analytics for Android. My issue is that because of two AndroidManifest (Vuforai and Flurry) file my Flurry log event is not calling because of the Manifest file conflict.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks
Yashesh

Answer (score 0):

If merge two file then Open your main Manifest file and second Manifest file, Copy second Manifest file data in main Manifest file and save it.

Comment: @Yashesh its send error or not show anything?? And where you paste manifest file code ??

Comment: It's not showing error. App works fine but flurry log event not sent to flurry.

Comment: @Yashesh i see the your manifest file. This your manifest file in this Vuforai and Flurry manifest code. ?

Comment: @Yashesh if you use only flurry its work and same as Vufor its work with single ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60946/discussion-between-yashesh-and-divyang-metalia).